# Reading from a filehandle reference in a subroutune

Tags: perl, reference, subroutine, filehandle

I'd like to pass a reference to a file handle to a subroutine, such that code in the sub can read from the file and the position in the file handle changes in the calling environment, rather like using a pointer in C.

This kind of thing:

```
open my $fh, '<', $somefile or die;

dosomething(\$fh);

sub dosomething
{
  my $fh_ref = shift;

  while (my $l = <$$fh_ref>)
  {
    print $l;
    print "\n";
  }
}
```

This gives this output instead of writing each line:

```
 GLOB(0x20b8b38)
```

Obviously I am dereferencing the file handle reference wrong.

Addendum:

```
while (my $l = readline($$fh_ref))
{
```

etc.

seems to do the trick. I am still interested in why the first approach doesn't work.

Comment: No need to create a ref to a scalar.  Just use `dosomething($fh);`.  Then there's no need to deref later.

Comment: @toolic: Yes, this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The diamond operator `<...>` has two meanings in Perl -- one corresponding to the `readline(HANDLE)` function and the other corresponding to `glob(EXPR)`. [How does perl decide which function to use?](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/RJBS/perl-5.24.0/pod/perlop.pod#I/O-Operators)

> If what's within the angle brackets is neither a filehandle nor a
>          simple scalar variable containing a filehandle name, typeglob, or
>          typeglob reference, it is interpreted as a filename pattern to be
>          globbed, and either a list of filenames or the next filename in the
>          list is returned, depending on context.  This distinction is determined
>          on syntactic grounds alone.  That means `<$x>` is always a `readline()`
>          from an indirect handle, but `<$hash{key}>` is always a `glob()`.  That's
>          because `$x` is a simple scalar variable, but `$hash{key}` is not--it's a
>          hash element.  Even `<$x >` (note the extra space) is treated as
>          `glob("$x ")`, not `readline($x)`.

The workarounds are to either use an explicit `readline` call

```
while (my $l = readline($$fh_ref)) ...
```

or to use a simpler expression inside the brackets.

```
my $fh42 = $$fh_ref;
while (my $l = <$fh42>) ...
```

Comment: ...Or, preferably, not to pass a reference to a scalar in the first place.